# VS Setup project install and uninstall msi

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project

I want to create the VS Setup MSI which will on install run the windows applications and get uninstall automatically. Using System.Configuration.Install.Installer class i am able to achieve the installation and running the windows application, but it is not getting uninstall. Request to please help on same. Note:- MSI must be 32 bit.

Using System.Configuration.Install.Installer class how to call uninstall method or uninstall event.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by installing and automatically uninstalling? On this msi there is existing library named[Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects).

Comment: Lets say i have sample.msi, once sample.msi is installation completed i am running abc.exe file in custom action of sample.msi. After the completion of abc.exe i want to uninstall the sample.msi file. So if tried to uninstall the sample.msi it give me fatal error or one more installation is in process.